# Skoda Fabia SDI 2005

Tags: skoda

I have many problems in my car (skoda fabia sdi 2005), which happened after the computer of the vehicle burning . 
I changed the computer but there are a problems in ABS light, wheel light and handbreak light with 3 sounds (beeb) on dashboard . what will the problem be??

Comment: For such a complicated issue you need to give us a huge amount of information. What lights are on when the car is running? How does it run? Are there any check engine lights? Why did the previous computer burn out? What module actually burnt out?

Comment: I do have the same kind of issue but mine was not burnt, Let me give you the proper explanation. Once the engine was started, the engine warning light, the glow plug light and the ABS light continues to glow, after a few KMs of drive the hand-break warning light start glows with the audio alert of 3 beeps. I replaced the break pads and break shoes as well as I checked all the ABS sensors and hand-break switch. Everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

### Please Update your Question

I will update my answer if you add more information. As finleyarcher said, we cannot help without adequate data. Please refer to the [Asking](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/asking) page in the help center for more information.

---

### Answer

From [what I've found](https://www.briskoda.net/forums/topic/24068-3-beeps-on-startup/), the 3 beeps indicates a low fluid level state. Could be coolant or any other fluid apparently.